# encounter malformed http response while deploying a docker registry

Tags: docker, certificate, windows-registry

I came across the following errors as running docker push docker push myregistry.com/testexpose command.

The push refers to a repository [myregistry.com/testexpose]

```
Put http://myregistry.com/v1/repositories/testexpose/: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"
```

The certificates has been built by following the docker [offical guide](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#using-self-signed-certificates).

I could see the docker running correctly.

```
[root@ip-10-1-1-229 docker]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
b28c6a3be012        registry:2          "/entrypoint.sh /e..."   35 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 5000/tcp   registry
```

Docker container logs could be seen as follows:

```
2017/07/02 01:56:12 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42218: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:12 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42224: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:13 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42230: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:13 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42236: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:14 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42242: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:14 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42248: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:15 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42254: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:15 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42260: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:15 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42266: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
2017/07/02 01:56:15 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:42272: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

It seems to be an authentication error, but the CN was set as `myregistry.com` during the creation of the x.509 certificate. Would any one figure out what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using HTTP to connect to HTTPS. Instead of port 80, you need to map port 443, and then use `https://myregistry.com...`

Comment: Could you say more?  I have what I think is the same problem (can make my own question if desired) where a registry is using tls and it isn't valid to `docker pull https://` since the pull syntax expects the raw domain and no protocol prefix.

Comment: I retract the question.  It turns out you must `docker login` for TLS endpoints.  Subsequent `docker pull` commands will use https and not try to use http.